# PHP input array question

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form which includes 3 date of birth inputs like the following:

```
  <label>Date of Birth</label>
  <input type='text' size='2' maxlength='2' name='DOB[2]' />
  <input type='text' size='2' maxlength='2' name='DOB[3]' />
  <input type='text' size='4' maxlength='4' name='DOB[1]' />
```

The order of the inputs work as `month/day/year`. I am sending this to my script which then implodes the DOB array like such (Thanks to @Matt H.):

```
if(isset($_userData['DOB']))
    $_userData['DOB'] = implode('-', $_userData['DOB']);
```

Now, the problem is, this implodes it to the improper format of `month/day/year`, which is not the order of the array I set, but the order of the inputs. Am I stuck with having to manually concatenate the array into the format I need for MySQL (year/month/day) ?

Comment: Yup, but on the other hand, more control there seems a good way to avoid obscure bugs. I'd go for explicitly setting the order any day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if(isset($_userData['DOB'])){
    ksort($_userData['DOB']);
    $_userData['DOB'] = implode('-', $_userData['DOB']);
}
```

This will sort the array `$_userData['DOB']` by key. Based on your input elements, it is going to become:

```
$_userData['DOB'] = array(
    1 => 'YYYY',
    2 => 'MM',
    3 => 'DD'
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sort the array first:

```
if(isset($_userData['DOB'])) {
    ksort($_userData['DOB']);
    $_userData['DOB'] = implode('-', $_userData['DOB']);
}
```

Comment: I get an error that invalid arguments are passed in the implode function. Do I have to do this outside of it first?

Comment: Yes, you do, sorry, ksort returns true/false.  I've edited my answer.